# testcafe selector does not find 'div' elements

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, css-selectors, testcafe

I'm experiencing a very strange bug using testcafe. On one of my websites I'm not able to select div-elements but I'm still able to select other elements. So

```
await t.click(Selector("span").withAttribute('id', 'foo'));
await t.click(Selector("p").withAttribute('id', 'foo'));
await t.click(Selector("button").withAttribute('id', 'foo'));
await t.click(Selector("input").withAttribute('id', 'foo'));
```

works fine while

```
await t.click(Selector("div").withAttribute('id', 'foo'));
```

will throw the following error:

> Function that specifies a selector can only return a DOM node, an
> array of nodes, NodeList, HTMLCollection, null or undefined. Use
> ClientFunction to return other values.

This only happens on one specific website of mine. What could this be? What could I have possibly done in my script to prohibit the testcafe selector to get "div" elements? Really out of ideas right now.

Comment: Does this `Selector("div").withAttribute('id', 'foo')` exist on your site? It seems there's been a bug in a similar situation but the element didn't exist on the site: https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/1240

Comment: Yes, the selector definitely exists on my site. I have no idea why I'm getting this error.

Answer (score 2):

This issue can occur if you pass a function with an incorrect return value as a Selector argument:

```
test('Return non-DOM node', async () => {
    await Selector(() => 'hey')();
});
```

However, the error should not occur if you use string as a parameter to specify your selector. Please check that you do not pass a function to your Selector object.

If your Selector is defined correctly and the issue still appears, please share the example (html page or public url to your site) and your full test code to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: I'm not passing a function, I'm using the basic annotation displayed above.

Unluckily the page is still confidential so I cannot show it to you. Do you have any other guesses what the issue could be? It must have something to do with the code that is used on that specific project.